# How to rollback messages in Activemq

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I want to send acknowledgement to `Activemq` when variable `x` value is equals to `1`.If it not equals to `1`,I want to redeliver messages to `Activemq`. Then only `Activemq` delivers that messages again to subscribers.For this I written the following programs.

MessageConsumer.java :

```
 public class Consumer extends HttpServlet {
 @Override
 protected void service(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
  try {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory=new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("admin","admin","tcp://localhost:61617");
RedeliveryPolicy policy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
policy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(1000L);
policy.setMaximumRedeliveries(RedeliveryPolicy.NO_MAXIMUM_REDELIVERIES);
connectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(policy);
connectionFactory.setUseRetroactiveConsumer(true);
Connection connection=connectionFactory.createConnection();
final Session session=connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Topic queue=session.createTopic("MessageTesting");
javax.jms.MessageConsumer consumer=session.createConsumer(queue);
//anonymous class
MessageListener listener = new MessageListener() {
        @Override
    public void onMessage(Message msg) {
        TextMessage msg1=(TextMessage)msg;
        try {
                String messageBody=msg1.getText();
                if (x==1) {
                   //Process was completely done,so I am sending acknowledge
                   session.commit();
                }  
                else {
                   //Process is not done sucessfully, So I want to redeliver messages, For this
                   session.rollback();
                 }
           }
          catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
           }

    }
};
consumer.setMessageListener(listener);
connection.start();
}
 }
```

Is this correct way to do this.can you suggest me,Is there any efficient way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you will have to :

Create a **ActiveMQConnectionFactory** to your binding address,
Create a **RedeliveryPolicy** and set it to **ActiveMQConnectionFactory**.
Create a **Session** and use **session.commit()** if true and **session.rollback()** if it failed.

These two links might help you:

http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html

http://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy.html

```
public class Consumer extends HttpServlet {
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1)
throws ServletException, IOException {
try {
...
MessageListener listener = new MessageListener() {
public void onMessage(Message msg) {
....
}
};
....
}
```

}

Comment: I read what you suggested.They are explaining about once redeliver attempts exceeds the `maximumRedeliveries` for individual message.That particular message send to `DLQ`. Why this concept was useful for me.I am using `Topic not queue` and non-transacted session. Can I use `Transacted sessions` for this.
I updated my question with my code. can you explain with some code.I written 2 programs.one for consumer and another one was `MessageListener`. As per my understanding If we want to use `rollback()` we need to `session` object,but it is in consumer program.How can I access in `MyListener`.

Comment: try creating your listener as anonymous inner class, make the session object final, then the session object will be available in consumer

Comment: you mean, Am I need to write `MYListener` inside consumer program.

Comment: I modified according to your code. also I am using `Topic` and `Transactedsesions`.
acknowledge mode was : `Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE`.can you check it once.

Comment: Think that should work.. Do reply after trying. This link might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576821/cant-get-activemq-to-resend-my-messages

Comment: Thank you.it's working great. I want to use durable subscribers. and also I have a doubt. Later If I add one more consumer to same `Topic`.Am I need to modify any code. As per I know, creating new consumer is nothing but copy paste the same code and change `className`.

Comment: I see from your edited code that, you are using commit() on else case also.. Shouldn't that be rollback() ?

Comment: Just now, I edited my question. it's working fine.check it once.whether is it correct way or not. Right now I am not using durable subscribers,because of this I am losing messages, which messages are published when consumer is in inactive state. So I want to use Durable subscribers. can you help me on this.I am very happy because of your communication I learn new stuff. Thanks. First let me know whether is it right or not(What I posted code in my question).

Comment: please can you check this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736355/how-to-save-messages-and-topics-in-activemq) .