# How to save messages and Topics in Activemq?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have a `Queue` and `Topic` with 2 messages in `Activemq`.If I restart `Activemq`.I am losing messages and also `Topic`.

Even If I restart `Activemq`,I don't want to lose any messages from any `Topic`and `Queue`.Is it possible.

I am using `Activemq 5.8.0`.

Comment: Look for queue/topic persistence in ActiveMQ: [ActiveMQ persistence](http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html)

Answer (score 0):

> A producer produces the message and send it to the Topic, which ever
>   consumer is running at that point of time, will receive the message.
>   If you want consumer which is not up now, but might be running in
>   future to get this message, you will have to tell the Broker to
>   persist the message and store the information that this perticular
>   consumer has not received the message.

If you have working code with-out durable subscriber, you will have to do the following changes.

In the consumer,
1. set the clinetId. Because Topic should know which consumer is yet to receive the message. Or has received the message.

```
Connection.setClientID(String)
```

2. Should be creating a durable subscriber for your topic

```
Connection.createDurableSubscriber()
```

3. Add your listener to this subscriber.

```
subscriber.setMessageListener(yourlistener)
```

4. Once you receive the message, you will have to acknowledge it

This link shows how it is done: But its in c# i guess.

http://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2011/08/16/jms-how-to-setup-a-durablesubscriber-with-a-messagelistener-using-activemq/

Read these links for more info :

http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-durable-queues-and-topics-work.html
http://activemq.apache.org/why-do-i-not-receive-messages-on-my-durable-topic-subscription.html
http://activemq.apache.org/manage-durable-subscribers.html